# How to get recordId in community page

Tags: lightning-web-components, community-cloud, onclickjavascript

Mypage.HTML

```
<template>
    <lightning-button
        onclick={handleClick}
        aria-haspopup="modal"
        label="Open My Modal">
    </lightning-button> 
    <p>Result: {result}</p>
    </template>
```

////////////////////
Mypage.JS

```
import { LightningElement, api } from "lwc";
import NAME_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Account.Name';
import MyModal from "c/myModal";

export default class MyPage extends LightningElement {
    nameField = NAME_FIELD;
   

    @api recordId;
    
    @api objectApiName;
    async handleClick() {
        console.log(this.recordId+ ' recordId');
        // console.log(this.nameField+ ' nameField');
        // console.log(this.currentPageReference.state.recId);
        const result = await MyModal.open({
            size: 'large',
            description: 'Accessible description of modal\'s purpose',
            content: this.recordId,

          //  content2: this.recordId,

           
        });
        // if modal closed with X button, promise returns result = 'undefined'
        // if modal closed with OK button, promise returns result = 'okay'
        console.log(result);
    }
}
```

//////////////
Mypage.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>45.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__AppPage</target>
        <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
        
          <target>lightning__HomePage</target>
        <target>lightning__Tab</target>
        <target>lightningCommunity__Page</target>
        <target>lightningCommunity__Default</target>
    </targets>
    <targetConfigs>
        <targetConfig targets="lightningCommunity__Default">
            <property
                name="recordId"
                type="String"
                label="Record Id"
                description="Automatically bind the page's record id to the component variable"
                default="{!recordId}" />
        </targetConfig>
    </targetConfigs>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

/////////Mymodel.html

```
<template>
  <lightning-modal-header label="My Modal Heading"></lightning-modal-header>
    <lightning-modal-body> Content: {recordId} 
      console.log(recordId)
      <lightning-record-edit-form
        record-id={content}
        object-api-name="Account"
        
    >
        <div class="slds-box">
            <lightning-input-field field-name="Name"> </lightning-input-field> 
            <lightning-input-field field-name="Phone"> </lightning-input-field>              
        </div>
        <lightning-button class="slds-m-top_small" variant="brand" type="submit" name="update" label="Update">
        </lightning-button>
    </lightning-record-edit-form>
    </lightning-modal-body>
    <lightning-modal-footer>
        <lightning-button label="OK" onclick={handleOkay}></lightning-button>
    </lightning-modal-footer>
</template>
```

/////////////////////

Mymodel.JS

```
import { api } from 'lwc';
import LightningModal from 'lightning/modal';

export default class MyModal extends LightningModal {
     @api content;
    @api recordId;
    @api content2;
    
     handleOkay() {
        console.log(recordId);
        this.close('okay');
    }
}
```

///////////////////MyModel.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
<apiVersion>45.0</apiVersion>
<isExposed>true</isExposed>
<targets>
<target>lightning__AppPage</target>
<target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
<target>lightning__HomePage</target>
<target>lightning__Tab</target>
<target>lightningCommunity__Page</target>
        <target>lightningCommunity__Default</target>

</targets>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various answers to this, including Mukul's answer here, that suggest not using the default for this target property. However, this works fine as long as you define this target property before adding the component into your Digital Experience page using the Builder.

So, similar to Mukul's answer, you need to update the LWC's metadata to ensure that you have the "recordId" target property for your "lightningCommunity__Default" target config, but here you should set the default as well:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>56.0</apiVersion>
    <description>Something.</description>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <masterLabel>Whatever</masterLabel>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
        <target>lightningCommunity__Page</target>
        <target>lightningCommunity__Default</target>
    </targets>
    <targetConfigs>
        <targetConfig targets="lightning__RecordPage">
        </targetConfig>
        <targetConfig targets="lightningCommunity__Default">
            <property name="recordId" label="Record Id" type="String" default="{!recordId}"/>
        </targetConfig>
    </targetConfigs>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

(My example above allows the LWC to be used on Lightning Record Pages and in Digital Experience pages)

When you subsequently drag-n-drop the component onto your page in the Digital Experience Builder you'll then see the property editor with the required "{!recordId}" value prefilled for the Record Id:

[image: Digital Experience Builder with component property editor]

This doesn't happen if you added the property after adding the component in the page.

At runtime, the Digital Experience page passes the actual record ID through into the component as long as the `recordId` expression variable is defined for that page.

Here's an example as to how that works for the generic Record Detail page. If you open that page in the Builder and click the cog (1) you will see that the URL includes a ":recordId" parameter that is part of the URL (2):

[image: Page configuration with recordId parameter]

That URL is like "/detail/:recordId".

The Digital Experience runtime takes the value in that part of the URL to get the value that is substituted by the expression "{!recordId}". The URL might look like ".../detail/003000000000123", so the recordId parameter is "003000000000123" and the expression "{!recordId}" results in "003000000000123" being passed to your LWC.

You might have the record ID passed as a query parameter too, in a custom page. That page might have a URL like "/my-page" in the Builder. However, you may have set things up so that page is navigated to with URL parameters at runtime. For example ".../my-page?recordId=003000000000123".

If the URL doesn't have a ":" delimited parameter matching a given expression variable name, the Digital Experience runtime automatically looks for a query parameter matching the variable name referenced in the expression, so again here the expression "{!recordId}" will be substituted by the required record ID, "003000000000123", using the query parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following property in the XML file after the **targets tag** -

```
        <targetConfigs>
            <targetConfig targets="lightningCommunity__Default">
                <property name="recordId" type="String" label="Record ID" description="Should be set to {!recordId}"/>
<!-- this will create a property on the community page-->
            </targetConfig>
        </targetConfigs>
```

Now when you see your component in community builder, you need to set the attribute like below -

[image]